# ST_LocateAlong strange behaviour around middle of Pacific

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

I am using ST_LocateAlong in order to find for a given track and timestamp the estimated position of the point at this timestamp, the timestamp being in the middle of the timestamps of my tracks.

It's work well except when the track is in the middle of Pacific, the returned point is not near the track at all but in middle of Atlantic.

the query looks like this:

```
SELECT ST_LocateAlong(ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePointM(track.longitude,
track.latitude, EXTRACT(epoch FROM track.time)) 
ORDER BY track.time ASC), 1620518400.0) FROM track 
WHERE id = ...
```

i am wondering if it is linked to the spatial reference system used. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Nearby the antimeridian? Maybe using a pacific-centered CRS like EPSG:3832 could help?

Comment: thanks this was the solution indeed. so by transforming the track into this new coordinates system and retransforming back to original coordinates system after having applied st_locatealong it worked well!

Comment: OK, so I added that as a solution.

Comment: Please do not alter the Question to contain your solution. See the the Help Center article [What should I do when someone answers my Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the points are near the antimeridian. Use a pacific-centered CRS like `EPSG:3832`.